# use config.xml to control how plugins are installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, config

I'm performing a test on and android app built. i want to use the config.xml to manipulate how some of the plugins are installed. currently i'm trying to take out vibrate from being added when compilation is started but its fails to work

```
<platform name="android">
        <preference name="Scheme" value="http" />
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <custom-preference delete="true" name="android-manifest/uses-permission/[@android:name='android.permission.VIBRATE']" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that by just adding a line in your config. I had to remove a permission last summer and I had to do it by creating a hook and running that after prepare. To do that add this to your config.xml:
`<hook src="customHooks/removePermissionHook.js" type="after_prepare" />`

```
(function () {
 'use strict';
 module.exports = function(ctx) {
if (ctx.opts.platforms.includes('android')) {
  const fs = require('fs');
  const gutil = require('gulp-util');
  const androidManifest = "platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml";
  const androidManifestPermission = "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.VIBRATE\" />"
  const androidJson = 'platforms/android/android.json';
  const androidJsonPermission =
      `{
          "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\\"android.permission.VIBRATE\\" />",
          "count": 1
        },`;
  // Show which hook is running
  gutil.log(gutil.colors.yellow('Running HOOK:'), gutil.colors.cyan('removePermission'));

  const removeTextFromFile = (fileName, stringToRemove) => {
    fs.readFile( fileName, "utf8", function( err, data ) {
      if (err) {
        console.warn( err );
        return;
      }

      let result = data.replace(stringToRemove, "");

      fs.writeFile( fileName, result, "utf8", function( err ) {
        if (err) {
          return console.warn( err );
        }
      });
    });
  };
  removeTextFromFile(androidManifest, androidManifestPermission);
  removeTextFromFile(androidJson, androidJsonPermission);
}
};
}());
```

You might have to tweak it a bit, the docs might help with that: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/appdev/hooks/